# Programatically Change Color Of ListBox SelectedItem Text

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a listbox that contains some items. I need to make it so when the MouseDoubleClick event is triggered, the selected listbox item's text changes color. I'm using C# WPF. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: I've researched this and tried snippets from other posts to no avail.

Comment: have you made any attempt to code it yourself?

Comment: Yup. I couldn't find a property of listBox.SelectedItem that held the color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an event handler to the ListBox event MouseDoubleClick and add this code:

```
private void ListBox_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    SolidColorBrush b = new SolidColorBrush();
    b.Color = Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 255);
    ((ListBoxItem)((ListBox)sender).SelectedItem).Foreground = b;
}
```

Then place your RGB colorcode in the brackets.

If you are not using only ListBoxItems use this Generic code:

```
private void ListBox_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    SolidColorBrush b = new SolidColorBrush();
    b.Color = Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 255);
    Type t = ((ListBox)sender).SelectedItem.GetType();
    if(t == new ListBoxItem().GetType())
        ((ListBoxItem)((ListBox)sender).SelectedItem).Foreground = b;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I got an error: Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem'.

Comment: Then you have to use ListBoxItem in your ListBox

Comment: I see it, but upon pasting it in I get two new errors: object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'object.GetType() and t is a variable but used like a type.

Comment: In the designer: Select your ListBox and search for "Items" in the Properties Tab. Click on the Button next to it. In the upcoming window you have a ComboBox at the lower left corner. There You can select the type of the Item you want to add. If you want to use my snippet you need to select and use ListBoxItem

Answer (score 0):

This might help you to get your task working from XAML itself.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
            Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
            Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" />
    <Setter Property="Padding"
            Value="2,0,0,0" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Border x:Name="Bd"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                             Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background"
                                TargetName="Bd"
                                Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected"
                                       Value="true" />
                            <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive"
                                       Value="false" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background"
                                TargetName="Bd"
                                Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}" />
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                             Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Put this into your Window resource.